# How can I create one List<Object> with a MapStruct List<String> and an Integer field?

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
public class SurveyAnswerEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int answerId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private SurveyQuestionEntity question;

    private String answer;

}
```

and

```
public class SurveyContentModel {
    private String question;
    private List<String> answerList;
}
```

and

```
public interface SurveyAnswerMapper {

    SurveyAnswerMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(SurveyAnswerMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "question.questionId", source = "questionId")
    SurveyAnswerEntity toEntity(String answer, Integer questionId);
    List<SurveyAnswerEntity> toEntityList(List<String> answer, Integer questionId);

}
```

I have a List array, and a single number. (DB-based Key)

The data in the List is different.
However, it is dependent on one number corresponding to the DB reference key.

List contains oneString, twoString, threeString

Numbers exist on their own.

That is, combining these two

You need to create a List.

key : 1
value : oneString
= Entity1

key : 1
value : twoString
= Entity2

key :1
value : threeString
= Entity3

It's like this.

error: The return type List is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.

When I delete questionId, it works fine. Perhaps a single field cannot be simply mapped to a List.

How can I create an Entity with the same Integer data for all List data?

Comment: Your description confuses me. To answer the question in your title, You can create a custom class that contains your MapStruct List<String> and Integer as fields and make a list of those custom objects. Hope that helps

Comment: Of course, your answer is also possible. But you have to create an additional object class, assign it, and use it again as a parameter.

I'm looking for a way to map two data obtained separately from each other at once.

Comment: You can keep them in a data structure that preserves ordering (array, LinkedList etc) and match them up based on index.

Comment: Thank you very much for your willingness to help. But the key is to hope not to create new classes or objects. (I've already had success with this approach.) I'd like to know if there is a feature in MapStruct that supports the way I intend to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no automatic way in MapStruct to support what you are looking for. You will need to write a custom mapping to achieve this.

What you could do though is to use `@Context` to help yourself.

e.g.

```
public interface SurveyAnswerMapper {

    SurveyAnswerMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(SurveyAnswerMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "question.questionId", expression = "java(questionId)")
    @Mapping(target = "answer", source = "answer")
    SurveyAnswerEntity toEntity(String answer, @Context Integer questionId);
    List<SurveyAnswerEntity> toEntityList(List<String> answer, @Context Integer questionId);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really made my day - i was just writing my own question.